# Generate Data Export SQL File Using Liquibase via Java API

Tags: java, mysql, liquibase

would like to generate an SQL file from liquibase via Java code replicating this command

```
java -jar liquibase.jar --changeLogFile="./data/filename" --diffTypes="data" generateChangeLog
```

I am using this as a replacement for a home grown SQL backup Java class

Comment: Just a helpful hint for the future. When asking a question, you may get better responses if you include things like:

all the steps you took (in this case, that might include what version of liquibase you are using, if there are other files involved, what platform you are on, what database you are using, etc.) 

what the expected results are

what the actual results were

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do what you want I think:

```
ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor = new FileSystemResourceAccessor();
Database db = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(yourJdbcConnection));
Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("data/filename", resourceAccessor, db);
try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)) {
    liquibase.update((Contexts) null, writer);
}
```

Comment: Where do I get the Contexts as the symbol cannot be resolved?

Comment: The FQDN is `liquibase.Contexts`

Comment: Just checking the update I run into an error parsing the filename, how will this work when I am looking to generate an actual file with SQL?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The example should take the liquibase changelog at `date/filename` and output the SQL that would be executed to `System.out`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an util method `liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils#doGenerateChangeLog` from the `liquibase-core.jar`. It uses same parameters as in your example with a command line.

In my project there is example of using this method:
https://github.com/0x100/liquibase-backuper-spring-boot-starter. This is a starter for Spring Boot, but I think it’s easy to understand how to use the method.